# Sort ArrayList of objects through one of its instance variables

Tags: java, arraylist

Helllo,

I have an ArrayList of OBJECTS (teams). They are football teams and I would like to sort them out through their points. Obviously I am fully aware ArrayLists are sorted via the order they are inserted.

But I have a TEAM class that has gamesWon, gamesLost, gamesTied and points based on a match result.

I have everything ready but figured that sorting out an ArrayList through it's points would be a cool feature to make.

I have read the Collections.sort(myArrayList) online, but this sorts based on ONE type of variable, and since I have objects within the ArrayList, I would like to sort this out.

Thank you.

Marco

Answer (score 3):

You should define a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this.

```
public class PointsBasedTeamComparator implements Comparator<Team> {
    public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
        //return the result of points comparison of t1 and t2
    }
}
```

And use it as follows

```
Collections.sort(teams, new PointsBasedTeamComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a `java.util.Comparator<Team>` that implements `compareTo` with the value that you want to check.
2. Use the sort method that accepts the `Comparator<Object>`. It will use the `compareTo` method of your `Comparator`, and not the one defined in `Team` (if any).
3. Enjoy!

Comment: I think this calls for `Comparator` rather than `Comparable`; being `Comparable` implies that the objects have a single natural order, whereas a `Comparator` is just some particular way of sorting them, of which there could be several.

Comment: Ok this is a bit confusing as I have never used Comparator, etc but I am going to read a bit more before I do.

Thanks a bunch guys!!